# How to order posts in wordpress template using WP_Quaries?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of my pages: array(53, 22, 18, 20).

I pass them to WP_Query this way

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => array(53, 22, 18, 20)));
```

How to loop them in my order array(53, 22, 18, 20). When I use this loop if

```
($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
```

My posts are shown in order 18, 20, 22, 53. I want them to be ordered by my custom order (ex. 53, 22,18, 20)? How to do that?

Comment: They talk about this [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-wp_query-without-sorting) but I guess there's no way to achieve this directly with WP_Query. I'd propose to create a custom field setting up the order and `orderby` this field or you could use a plugin like [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => array(53, 22, 18, 20),
            'orderby' => 'none',));
```

Worked for me. That shows posts in order how my values to array are set. 
[Found solution here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)